# Floating area at report header in Crystal Reports

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to generate a Crystal report with 2 requirements

- The first page (report header) contains a sidebar on the right side which will print the company informations.
- A text which can potentially span a lot of pages should start at the first page.

Here is an example of the result I want to achieve:

```
-------------------------------------------------    
|                                   |           |
| HeaderArea                        |  Logo     |
|                                   |           |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
|                                   |  Info     |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     | Info      |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     | Info      |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     | Info      |
-------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------
|                                   |  Logo     |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When I place a parameter-field for the text-content in the report header section something like this will happen on the second page instead:

```
-------------------------------------------------    
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text     |           |
|                                   |  Logo     |
```

The parameter-field will resize the report header section so that the page-break is not detected correctly.

I already tryed putting the parameter in the detail-section: Now the pagebrak is ok but my text does not start left to the side-bar but "waits" until this is printed and startes below the report header.

What can I do to achieve a sidebar area in report header with Crystal?

Edit:

Here is my current report designer including the recommendation of @Siva:

[image: Designer]

And here are the current results:

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

See how the page header is pushed away on second page?

Comment: Where are you placing the text and where are you placing the logo....are you splitting only header or details a swell

Comment: @Siva Everything is placed in Report Header section. No splits are applied in Section Manager.

Comment: Ok so problem is not second page logo is displayed at then end after the text is totally printed...is that correct

Comment: Yes. The page change is not happening right because the text is too long in Report Header and the header is growing so that it spans 2 pages. Then it'll print out the page header of the second page at whatever position it has now. I know that this would be ease if the text is placed in detail area because then page breaks are detected correctly but I can't do that because the text would start under the right bar then.

Comment: you can try sub reports.. take a sub report and supress all sections and place the data in details now place the sub report in report header of main report... this should solve the issue

Comment: @Siva I've tried that out. Still same problem. I edited my question so you can see screenshots of it.

Comment: once data in report header is completed then only page header will start. since in your case data in report header spanned to second page then page header started from second page.. if you need logo to be in first page then you need to place the logo in sub report page header and then you data in this way you get logo in first page.. if this is not possible then place the logo in report header of main report so that you get logo on first page and from second page page header will print the logo in this case you need to make sure that from second page page header should start

Comment: @Siva Thank you. I think what I want is impossible with Crystal because one area is always treated as a block spanning the complete width of a page. That mus be the reason no one makes company layouts this way :-). Thx anyway.